# Increase execution time limit in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am using querecus to use PHP in Google App Engine. I get timeout error when using it since it has lots of files to process.

I tried

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

and I tried to disable the execution time limit via PHP, but all failed.

I get server error on app engine due to this, is there any alternative way to disable timeout in GAE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Execution time of script limited by GAE environment, you can't change it.

It limit 60 seconds for frontend request, 600 seconds for cron/task handlers.

Also you can use backend, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends (edit: backend is a deprecated option now)

Backend server have no limit time for execution query.

Answer (score 1):

No for a frontend.

You'll probably need to run querecus in a [backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview).

Answer (score 1):

Long running tasks can be run with task queues.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/taskqueue/

> Because tasks are executed as App Engine requests targeted at services, they are subject to stringent deadlines. Tasks handled by automatic scaling services must finish in ten minutes. Tasks handled by basic and manual scaling services can run for up to 24 hours.