# Download large file from external server using Google AppEngine with php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, download

I am experimenting with Google AppEngine and trying to download file from external server to my local machine using simple download script in php hosted at AppEngine.

Sample code snippet is as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: "' . $mime . '"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
}

readfile($url);
```

This is working fine for small size of the file. But it is failing for larger files due to 60 second execution time limitation of GAE. Is there any workaround to accomplish this type of task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase Execution time limit in Google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593014/increase-execution-time-limit-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: @magnetik as user uploads to GCS are exempted from 60 seconds limitation, I am looking for the solution like that but for file downloads.

Comment: In PHP, the time for user upload is limited by max_input_time (it's input from PHP side) and it's a different value from execution time, so it's a duplicate ^^

Comment: @magnetik not agree with you since we can't change the 60 seconds limitation.

Comment: The 60 second deadline applies to auto-scaling modules, but you can use Basic Scaling.  See [scaling options] here(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/).

Answer (score 1):

i can't add comment

from where you are reading file if its from Google Cloud Storage then you can configure your bucket as a static website. read more : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

and use Manual Scaling

> > Requests can run indefinitely. A manually-scaled instance can choose to handle /_ah/start and execute a program or script for many hours without returning an HTTP response code.
>
> read more :: [about scaling_types on google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#scaling_types)

you can save file Google Cloud Storage then access.

if i misunderstand sorry i am also trying to learn Google AppEngine(php) from last month :p another noob

Comment: I want to make point here: due to memory limitations in GAE its failing to handle large files - (got this from logs)

Comment: bro can you tell from where you are reading file GCS or remote server ??

Answer (score 1):

If the file is stored in GCS, you could serve the file directly without the 60s limit. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/public_access#serving_files_directly_from_google_cloud_storage for more details.

Comment: File is not stored in GCS.

Comment: You probably should then.